# Using Asterisk for IVR calls without internet connectivity

Tags: asterisk

I am thinking about using Asterisk as an IVR for a project in Burundi, in a place where we often lose internet connection. I'd like the Asterisk server to deliver IVR calls through, say, an Android gateway connected to the local phone provider.

It's all about using Asterisk without the VoIP layer. Does someone have any experience with this?

Comment: What is "an Android gateway connected to the local phone provider"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton An Android smartphone with a local SIM card, on the same local network.

Comment: Nevermind Asterisk, is _Android_ even capable of that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Honestly I don't know yet. I have found this post http://www.stocksy.co.uk/articles/Networks/use_an_old_mobile_phone_as_a_gsm_gateway_in_asterisk/, where a standard phone is paired to Asterisk via Bluetooth. It could perfectly suit our needs.

Comment: Take a look at [chan_mobile](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/chan_mobile) which is a channel driver to use Bluetooth-connected phones as FXO devices; I remember using it with an iPhone but I wouldn't recommend using it in production though. [chan_dongle](http://wiki.e1550.mobi/doku.php?id=introduction) might be a better option if you can buy compatible hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you have landline you can use sip gate to convert your fxs to sip and then use it with `chan_sip`.

I use sipura spa3000(bought for $30 on aliexpress) at home with landline and asterisk to filter phone ads by IVR, get my voicemail to email etc.

Everything works pretty stable.

And for mobile network connection I'd rather use [chan_celliax](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Connecting+to+the+Cellular+Network) - no Bluetooth involved yet dirt cheap and should be reliable.